# Leak in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, memory-leaks

my app is nearly finished but a leak has appeared.

After having spent an hour trying to find out how to solve this link, I can't find a solution. I'm sure one of you will help me out :)

[Here is the screenshot from XCode](http://i56.tinypic.com/1588ufs.png)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating a NSSortDescriptor without releasing it. The analyzer is pointing you at the line already.

To resolve that issue you have to replace

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distanceFromHome" ascending:YES]];
```

with

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distanceFromHome" ascending:YES] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an autorelease to the sortdescriptor that you inline alloc/init and add to that array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you assign the NSSortDescriptor a variable and release it after you used it? For me the leak has to do with the NSSortDescriptor. But that you can find out very fast.